# Listen/Capture HTTP Request Events via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an Flash MP3 Player that I am planning to use on my site, and what I am attempting to do (since the Flash element itself doesn't have a built in callback) is to listen for any HTTP Request it may make. Currently I can see the HTTP request form within my Chrome Timeline, and it tells me exactly the name and location of each files being requested as it is running through the playlist —- it shows up as "Send Request". The purpose for me attempting to do this is to possibly grab the file name, scan it via PHP, and return its ID3 image to the browser via jQuery. Is this possible?

**Retrieved from Chrome Timeline:**
*Send Request - Details
Self Time   0ms
Aggregated Time 0ms0ms0ms
Duration    303ms (at 1.49s)
Resource    Track-02.mp3
Request Method  GET
Used Heap Size  23.87MB of 41.62MB*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not provide an API for listening for any HTTP request.

Something you could try is serving the mp3 files via a script. This script could then store the loaded file's details somewhere. Then have your JS code query another script which returns the stored details.

Comment: OK well instead of listening for an incoming resource, is it possible to listen to a page's object which is making a call for a resource? And if so, how would I go about listening for it if the flash app doesn't have a documented method?

Comment: I'm afraid the flash app would need to provide the event for you. Have you considered rolling your own mp3 player, or using HTML5 audio? You could try something like SoundManager 2 which might have the features you need: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: Thanks for the help... I decided to continue with DewPlayer, but scrapped the XML playlist functionality for the simple classic install but added standalone javascript playback functionality. At this point I only wish the DewPlayer had an oncomplete event so I could program in an automatic skip command via javascript. Currently you have to manually trigger each track in the playlist.